# Sending POST data with Java

Tags: java, parsing, post

Ok, so the place I work at posts the weekly work schedule online and basically, I would like to write a program (which I will eventually be turning into an Android app, so I am writing the program in Java) to send data to the website (my username and password), then once it has logged in, to grab the schedule from the website. Once I have grabbed the schedule, I will parse it for the events (which I plan to automatically add to my phones calendar as events).

Anyway, I am having a bit of trouble doing this. So, basically, I made a little Java function to send POST data to the website, it looks like this:

```
public void test1 (){
    try {

        // First, set the URL to connect to
        String url = "https://mywalmart.com/cleartrust/ct_logon_en.html";

        // Next set the character encoding
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        // Format the query string
        String query = (new String()).format ("auth_mode=%s&user=%s&password=%s&x=%s&y=%s", 
                URLEncoder.encode("basic", charset), 
                URLEncoder.encode("...", charset), 
                URLEncoder.encode("...", charset),
                URLEncoder.encode("111", charset),
                URLEncoder.encode("36", charset));

        // Open a connection to the website, set a 10 second timeout, and set it to POST
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Mimic Mozilla web browser
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "mywalmart.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://.../cleartrust/ct_logon_en.html");

        // Send the POST data to the host
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        } finally {
            if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        // Get the headers sent to us, and display them all.
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields ();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.entrySet ())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey ();
            for (String value : entry.getValue ())
                System.out.println (key + ": " + value);
        }

        // Get the input stream for the HTML portion
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner (response);

        // Display all of the HTML
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println (in.nextLine ());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The form on the website that I am trying to mimic a connection to is as such (excluding some useless <div> tags and such):

```
<form name="ctlogonform" action="ct_logon_en.html" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="auth_mode" value="basic" />
    <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="image" src="images/btnLogin.jpg" />
</form>
```

Now, all that it returns when I run the program is this:

```
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 8069
Content-Type: text/html
```

followed by the standard HTML code of the webpage.

So I then created a test PHP webpage, with the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POST Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    All header data:<br>
<?php
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value<br>\n";
}
?><br>
    All variables set via POST are here:<br>
<?php 
foreach($_POST as $vblname => $value) echo $vblname . ' = ' . $value . "<br>\n"; 
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And, if I run the exact same script as above, except with the created PHP page, I get the following:

```
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 02:36:48 GMT
Content-Length: 1268
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POST Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    All header data:<br>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0<br>
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<br>
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7<br>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate<br>
Referer: https://mywalmart.com/cleartrust/ct_logon_en.html<br>
Host: bf-test.horizon-host.com<br>
Connection: keep-alive<br>
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br>
Content-Length: 60<br>
<br>
    All variables set via POST are here:<br>
auth_mode = basic<br>
user = ...<br>
password = ...<br>
x = 111<br>
y = 36<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, that tells me that I am successfully sending the POST data, and I am setting my headers correctly, the only problem is that the website my job uses isn't picking it up, or I am not sending it to the correct website. I have tried both https://mywalmart.com/cleartrust/ct_logon_en.html and https://mywalmart.com/ct_logon_en.html, yet they both do the same thing, and it doesn't send me a redirect either.

So, now that that's all covered! My question is, how could I successfully send the POST data to the website to mimic a web browser, so that I could access the page that would normally be accessed after a successful login?

(also, I have put '...' in places of various places, such as the URL of my work website, my username/password, etc.)

(Update: I had masked 'mywalmart.com' with '...', however, I realized that with a simple Google search of 'ct_logon_en.html' you would be able to find the original URL, so I have no real reason to attempt to hide it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer the question you have..

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/primer.html.

Try using the http client library. Its a lot more robust library.

Comment: Thank you, the link looks promising, I will read it and see if I am able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try hitting a URL that's not https (perhaps one that you control), and then spying on the output with Wireshark. Hit it from your program and from the browser and verify that you're encoding your form data correctly.

If that's not the issue, then I would next guess cookies, but that's just a guess.